# Max condition in Integer programming and MILP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

Assume you have 2 binary variables $b$ and $c$. Suppose you want another binary variable, $a$ to be $\max(b,c)$ always. How would you represent this in the constraints of an integer program or of a mixed integer linear program (assuming it can't be done in an IP)?

**EDIT:** The following constraints would work for setting $a = \max(b,c)$:

$a \geq b$
$a \geq c$
$a \leq b+c$

This can be verified by both a truth table and by case analysis.

**I still haven't understood exactly *how* the method described below is incorrect.**

I have tried the following method (although there are some possible issues in the truth table):

Introduce another binary variable, $z$. Now, put the conditions:

$a \geq b$
$a \geq c$
$a \leq b + z$
$a \leq c + 1 - z$
$b \geq c - z$

Doing case analysis:

1. $b = 0, c = 0$: For any $z\in\{0,1 \}$, all the constraints are only true for $a=0$.
2. $b = 0, c = 1$: For $z=0$, the 5th constraint isn't satisfied. For $z=1$, all the constraints are true for $a=1$.
3. $b = 1, c = 0$: For $z=1$, the 1st and 4th constraints can't be satisfied together. For $z=0$, all the constraints are true for $a=1$.
4. $b = 1, c = 1$: For any $z\in\{0,1 \}$, all the constraints are true for $a=1$.

Does this case analysis mean that the set of constraints indeed represents $a=\max(b,c)$? I am unsure because of the following "issues" with the truth table.

1. $a=1,b=0,c=1,z=0$: The constraints aren't satisfied => the truth table value is false. However, $a=1,b=0,c=1$ should always be true for $a=\max(b,c)$.
2. $a=1,b=1,c=0,z=1$: The constraints aren't satisfied => the truth table value is false. However, $a=1,b=1,c=0$ should always be true for $a=\max(b,c)$.

How should we resolve the "issues" with the case analysis and the truth table?

Answer (score 0):

The version with $z$ is technically correct. The two "solutions" you identify as issues each violate a constraint and thus are excluded from the feasible region. The solver will rule out both.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat automatic way to obtain the desired constraints via conjunctive normal form:
$$
a \iff b \lor c \\
(a \implies (b \lor c)) \land ((b \lor c) \implies a) \\
(\lnot a \lor (b \lor c)) \land (\lnot (b \lor c) \lor a) \\
(\lnot a \lor b \lor c) \land ((\lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor a) \\
(\lnot a \lor b \lor c) \land (\lnot b \lor a) \land (\lnot c \lor a) \\
((1 - a) + b + c \ge 1) \land ((1 - b) + a \ge 1) \land ((1 - c) + a \ge 1) \\
(b + c \ge a) \land (a \ge b) \land (a \ge c)
$$